Definability in pure-second order logic
Are the universe and the empty set the only definable sets without parameters in the language of pure second-order logic? TIA

What is the ambient structure? If it is a pure set (= no additional structure), then the answer is yes and has nothing to do with SOL: in a pure set any "reasonble" logic can only define the empty set and the universe, since those are the only sets which are invariant under automorphisms.

Thanks! No additional structure. Where can I find proofs that the relevant  logical notions are invariant under automorphisms?

Lavinia, I posted a further explication of Noah's comment.

Let me try to help by explicating the argument Noah mentioned. I think this is part of logic folklore—it amounts at bottom to the facts that every permutation of a pure set is an isomorphism, and isomorphisms preserve truth.
Specifically, in the language of pure second-order logic, you have a a domain $D$ of individuals, the domain of discourse, which exhibits no additional structure—no relations (except $=$), no named constants, no functions. The first order quantifiers $\exists x$ and $\forall x$ range over the elements of $D$, and the second-order quantifiers $\exists X$ range over the subsets and relations on $D$.
Since the domain $D$ has no atomic structure, it follows immediately that every permutation of the domain $\pi:D\to D$ is an automorphism, an isomorphism of the structure with itself. From this, it follows that $D\models\varphi[a,b,c,R,S,T]$, where $a,b,c$ are individuals from the domain and $R,S,T$ are relations on $D$, if and only if $D\models\varphi[\pi(a),\pi(b),\pi(c),\pi(R),\pi(S),\pi(T)]$ for any formula $\varphi$, whether in first-order or second-order logic (or higher-order).
This can be proved by induction on formulas. It is true for atomic formulas, since $\pi$ respects $=$ and we have transformed the second-order parameters to their images under $\pi$, and it combines inductively via Boolean combinations and first-order quantifiers. The second-order quantifiers are also preserved, for essentially the same reason—if there is a relation $R$ on $D$ fulfilling $\exists R\ \varphi[a,b,c]$, then $D$ satisfies $\varphi[a,b,c,R]$ and so by induction it satisfies $\varphi[\pi(a),\pi(b),\pi(c),\pi(R)]$, which means that $D$ fulfills $\exists R\varphi[\pi(a),\pi(b),\pi(c)]$.
Basically, any permutation is an isomorphism of the pure set $D$ with itself, trivially so, and isomorphisms preserve truth, regardless of the order.
It now follows that if you have a definable class $\{\ d\in D\mid\varphi(d)\ \}$ in $D$, with no parameters, then if it contains any point at all, it will contain all points, since there are permutations moving any $d$ to any other $d'$. So the only definable classes without parameters are the empty set or the universal class.

Note that $=$ is definable in second-order logic without $=$, since $a=b\iff\forall U\ (Ua\leftrightarrow Ub)$.

That said, there is a nontrivial notion of "SOL without equality" - see here.

I don't view the ordinary SOL notion as "naive", as you say, but natural.
